# add new contact to existing contactgroup ews api

Tags: c#, outlook, contacts, exchangewebservices

I've been trying to figure out this API for the past 1½ day, but now im struggling hard with getting a newly created contact added to a already existing group.

I have created a group the first time I ran the program with the following line of code:

```
    public static ContactGroup CreateGroup(ExchangeService service)
    {
        // Create a new contact group object.
        ContactGroup myContactGroup = new ContactGroup(service);

        // Give the group a name.
        myContactGroup.DisplayName = "Test Contact Group";

        // Save the group.
        myContactGroup.Save();

        return myContactGroup;
    }
```

Then i've added a contact to the group with the following piece of code:

```
    public static void AddContactToGroup(ContactGroup myContactGroup, Contact contact)
    {
        myContactGroup.Members.AddContactEmailAddress(contact, EmailAddressKey.EmailAddress2);
        myContactGroup.Update(ConflictResolutionMode.AlwaysOverwrite);
```

Now I want to create a new contact with the following code:

```
    public static Contact tempCont(ExchangeService service)
    {
        Contact contact = new Contact(service);
        contact.GivenName = "Jonas";
        contact.Surname = "Jonassen";
        contact.FileAsMapping = FileAsMapping.SurnameCommaGivenName;
        contact.PhoneNumbers[PhoneNumberKey.HomePhone] = "12345678";
        contact.EmailAddresses[EmailAddressKey.EmailAddress1] = new EmailAddress("jonas@jonassen.dk");

        PhysicalAddressEntry paEntry1 = new PhysicalAddressEntry();
        paEntry1.Street = "123 Main Boulevard";
        paEntry1.City = "Kbh";
        paEntry1.State = "";
        paEntry1.PostalCode = "1200";
        paEntry1.CountryOrRegion = "Denmark";
        contact.PhysicalAddresses[PhysicalAddressKey.Home] = paEntry1;

        contact.Save();

        return contact;
    }
```

Now I would like to add this new contact to the exisiting contactGroup. The problem is, that I cant get hold of "myContactGroup". Im guessing I have to find the ID of the ContactGroup, or maybe something totally different. I honestly dont know how to figure this out. Any help would be appriciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need to do is Find the ContactGroup you want to add the contact to eg use a SearchFilter to do this and then just use the Add Member method to add the contact to the group eg

```
            ItemView ItemView = new ItemView(1);
        SearchFilter cntGroup = new SearchFilter.IsEqualTo(ItemSchema.ItemClass, "IPM.DistList");
        SearchFilter cntGroupName = new SearchFilter.IsEqualTo(ContactGroupSchema.DisplayName, "Test Contact Group");
        SearchFilter sfCol = new SearchFilter.SearchFilterCollection(LogicalOperator.And) { cntGroup, cntGroupName };

        FolderId ContactFolder = new FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.Contacts, "user@domain.com");
        FindItemsResults<Item> fiCntResults = service.FindItems(ContactFolder, sfCol, ItemView);
        if (fiCntResults.Items.Count == 1)
        {
            ContactGroup contactGroup = (ContactGroup)fiCntResults.Items[0];
            Contact Contact2 = new Contact(service);
            Contact2.EmailAddresses[EmailAddressKey.EmailAddress1] = new EmailAddress("blah@blah.dk");
            Contact2.Subject = "Blah";
            Contact2.Save();
            GroupMember gm = new GroupMember(Contact2,EmailAddressKey.EmailAddress1);             

            contactGroup.Members.Add(gm);
            contactGroup.Update(ConflictResolutionMode.AlwaysOverwrite);

        }
```

Cheers
Glen

Comment: That is a much better method than my answer. Very sleek code, Glen!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Ultroman the Tacoman. I went with Glen's answer, but I managed to work a bit with your post too, and made a solution that would work too (just to get out the ContactGroup id, which I needed to add a new contact to a specific group. Code will look like this, if I went "your way":

```
    public static ContactGroup FindContactGroup(ExchangeService service, String groupName)
    {
        // Instantiate the item view with the number of items to retrieve from the Contacts folder.
        ItemView view = new ItemView(9999);

        // Request the items in the Contacts folder that have the properties that you selected.
        FindItemsResults<Item> contactItems = service.FindItems(WellKnownFolderName.Contacts, view);

        // Loop through all contacts 
        foreach (Item item in contactItems)
        {
            //Check to see if ContactGroup
            if (item is ContactGroup)
            {
                //Get the contact group
                ContactGroup contactGroup = item as ContactGroup;
                if (contactGroup.DisplayName == groupName)
                {                        
                    return contactGroup;
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Only problem I see, is that this solution would use a bit more memory then Glen's answer, since it has to go through every contact.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the code from this other stackoverflow answer, from the comment "//You can get the ItemID with the following code." and downwards. https://stackoverflow.com/a/19663185/1289974

Comment: Thanks Ultroman the Tacoman. I went with Glen's answer, but I managed to work a bit with your post too, and made a solution that would work too (just to get out the ContactGroup id, which I needed to add a new contact to a specific group. Code will look like this, if I went "your way":